# ActionBar setTitle() with sdk version 8 on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hi this is short question but very important for me.

I defined an `ActionBar` object. Then I set title to action bar with my specific `String` like below. But the problem is about minimum SDK version.

I want to use minimum sdk version 8 but `ActionBar` enforces me to sdk version **11**. Is there way to solve this problem?

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(country_name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.app.ActionBar` itself is only available on API Level 11+. If you want to use an action bar on earlier versions of Android, you will need some form of backport, such as [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Comment: Hmmmm. There should be a faq section in SO, don't you think? :-/

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish that by

```
ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setTitle("some title");
```

As describe [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) on Android developer site.

```
getSupportActionBar() // is the Support library version of getActionBar()
```